# How can I pass arguments for a subroutine from the command line

Tags: perl, tcsh

First off, my background is primarily in Python and I am relatively new at using Perl.

I am using tcsh for passing options into my .pl file.

In my code I have:

```
if( scalar @ARGV != 1)
{
    help();
    exit;
}

# Loading configuration file and parameters
our %configuration = load_configuration($ARGV[0]);

# all the scripts must be run for every configuration
my @allConfs = ("original");

sub Collimator 
{ 
     my $z = -25.0; 
     my %detector = init_det();
     
     $detector{"pos"}         = "0*cm 0.0*cm $z*cm"
}


foreach my $conf ( @allConfs )
{ 
    $configuration{"variation"} = $conf ;
    
     #other geometries ....
    
    Collimator();
}
```

I want to add something that allows me to change the parameters of the subroutine in the .pl file from the command line. Currently, to generate the geometry I pass the following command into the tcsh CLI: perl file.pl config.dat. What I want is to be able to pass in something like this: perl file.pl config.dat -20.0.

I'm thinking that I need to add something to the effect of:

```
if($ARGV[1]){
    $z = ARGV[1]}
```

However, I am not sure how to properly implement this. Is this something that I would specify within the subroutine itself or outside of it with the loading of the configuration file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a library to handle command-line arguments, and [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long) is excellent

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Getopt::Long;

my ($config_file, @AllConfs); 
my ($live, $dry_run) = (1, 0);
my $z;

GetOptions( 
    'config-file=s'  => \$config_file, 
    'options-conf=s' => \@AllConfs, 
    'geom|g=f'       => \$z,
    'live!'          => \$live,
    'dry-run'        => sub { $dry_run = 1; $live = 0 },
    # etc
);

# Loading configuration file and parameters
# (Does it ===really=== need to be "our" variable?)
our %configuration = load_configuration($config_file);

my @data_files = @ARGV;  # unnamed arguments, perhaps submitted as well
```

Options may be abbreviated as long as they are unambiguous so with my somewhat random sample above the program can be invoked for example as

```
prog.pl --conf filename -o original -o bare  -g -25.0  data-file(s)
```

(Or whatever options for `@AllConf` are.) Providing explicitly `g` as another name for `geom` makes it a proper name, not an abbreviation (it doesn't "compete" with others).

Note that one can use `--` or just `-`, and choose shorter or long(er) names for convenience or clarity etc.  We get options, and there is a lot more than this little scoop, see docs.

Once the (named) options have been processed the rest on the command line is available in `@ARGV`, so one can mix and match arguments that way.  Unnamed arguments are often used for file names.  (The module offers a way to deal with those in some capacity as well.)

Answer (score 1):

```perl
if ( @ARGV != 2 ) {
   help();
}

my ( $path, $z ) = @ARGV;
```

Answer (score -1):

perl gets input as list, so you can get its value using @ARGV or using $ARGV[0] and $ARGV[1]

```
die if ($#ARVG != 1);
#the first argument
print "$ARGV[0]\n";
#the second argument
print "$ARGV[1]\n"
```